# C++ How do I loop through strings within an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm required to check for the total number of vowels in a given string array but I can't figure out how to loop through each element of the array...I know how to loop through a string array itself:

```
int countAllVowels(const string  array[], int   n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
return(vowels);
}
```

But how do I actually investigate each element of the array?

Comment: std::string has operator[] and knows its size.

Comment: decompose the problem: write a function to count vowels in a single string first.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through each `char` of the `std::string`

```
int countAllVowels(const string  array[], int   n)
{
    static const std::string all_vowels = "aeiou";
    int vowels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (char c : array[i])
        {
            if (all_vowels.find(c) != std::string::npos)
                vowels += 1;
        }
    }
    return(vowels);
}
```

Alternatively this be done using a couple of functions from `<algorithm>`

```
std::size_t countAllVowels(std::vector<std::string> const& words)
{
    return std::accumulate(words.begin(), words.end(), 0, [](std::size_t total, std::string const& word)
           {
               return total + std::count_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c)
                              {
                                  static const std::string all_vowels = "aeiou";
                                  return all_vowels.find(c) != std::string::npos;
                              });
           });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two loops, the outer one for the array of strings, the inner one for the characters of a particular string in an array. Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
int countAllVowels(std::string array[], int n){
    std::vector<char> vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    int countvowels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (auto ch : array[i]){
            if (std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch) != vowels.end()){
                countvowels++;
            }
        }
    }
    return countvowels;
}
int main(){
    std::string arr[] = { "hello", "world", "the quick", "brown fox" };
    std::cout << "The number of vowels is: " << countAllVowels(arr, 4);
}
```